# Run an MSBuild target after a failed build

Tags: msbuild

My custom MSBuild tasks performs some steps before and after the actual build. It is essential that the steps after the build are always executed to clean up some files. I currently have two targets defined:

```
<Target Name="NrtPatchAssemblyInfo" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
```

and

```
<Target Name="NrtRestoreAssemblyInfo" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
```

The first one is always executed, but the second only runs after a successful build. If the build failed by the compiler, for example due to a syntax error in a code file, the second target isn't run.

What can I do to change this and always have the second task executed?

I couldn't find a list of target names MSBuild usually uses. These names are just copied from other sources.

Answer (score 4):

MsBuild stops running any further targets when an error occurs (unless ContinueOnError is modified somewhere but you can't go edit all installed msbuild files to get that working). One solution is to use the [OnError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/onerror-element-msbuild) element. This has to be set on the target which fails (or a parent of that target, I assume) so you'll have to select one which is used in the actual build and override it. For a C++ build you'd override the Build target, copy the definition from Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets and add OnError. Example code (must be inserted in the project file after the Microsoft.Cpp.targets Import!):

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
<Target Name="RunOnError">
  <Message Text="OOPS!" />
</Target>
<Target
    Name="Build"
    Condition="'$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' != 'true'"
    DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)"
    Returns="$(TargetPath)">
  <OnError ExecuteTargets="RunTargetAfterBuild" />
</Target>
```

To figure out which targets get executed just run the build with Detailed verbosity.

Comment: Not any more targets when one fails? How can I then do cleanup work or anything that needs to be done after an error? Copying Visual Studio infrastructure isn't an option for me (yet).

Comment: You could also remove the need to have cleanup work: much easier fix imo. Make a copy of whatever file you want to patch assembly info for, copy it to the intermediate directory or so, and use that copy in the build. It doesn't matter if the changes to the copy don't get reverted.

Comment: I finally got back to this topic. I've changed my tool to not patch and restore the file in place but save the modified file to obj\ and use that (Include) instead of the original file (Remove).